# Modificações no modelo e banco de dados relacional

Tags: banco-de-dados, orientação-a-objetos, modelo-relacional, ddd

Os requisitos para o desenvolvimento de um sistema em geral se modificam com o tempo. Diversas abordagens para o desenvolvimento de software como métodos ágeis e Domain-Driven Design inclusive encorajam uma abordagem iterativa na qual os nos aprofundamos com relação às reais necessidades de um sistema com o passar do tempo.

Além disso, ao construir qualquer sistema é muito importante conhecer o domínio do problema sendo resolvido e, no caso, esse conhecimento se aprofunda com o tempo.

Conforme os usuários finais vão utilizando o sistema desenvolvido também acontece de eles reconhecerem pontos que precisam ser modificados, pois houve algum requisito que foi esquecido ou que não foi bem compreendido. Inclusive, pelo que eu já li existem abordagens que encorajam que o software seja desenvolvido por partes e que conforme já tenham partes funcionando os usuários já tenham acesso para validar o que foi feito e prover esse feedback.

Até aí tudo bem. O problema maior é o seguinte: quando o sistema já está sendo usado passa a existir um banco de dados real de produção contendo os dados reais dos usuários. Esses dados, considerando bancos de dados relacionais, são representações em tabela dos objetos do modelo de domínio.

Agora, vamos supor que uma modificação é necessária no modelo de domínio que retira algumas propriedades e/ou coloca outras. Um exemplo seria um dado que atualmente é representado em uma única propriedade, mas vai passar a ser representado em várias, ou então algum dado que não existia antes e foi colocado.

Modificar o modelo de domínio é relativamente fácil, especialmente se estamos usando orientação a objetos do jeito certo. É claro que quanto maior o sistema mais a modificação pode impactar, mas mesmo assim é algo mais tratável, pois pode ser trabalhado inteiramente no ambiente de desenvolvimento.

Por outro lado, ao aplicar modificações desse tipo, o modelo não fica mais sincronizado com o banco. Uma nova estrutura de tabelas seria necessária para acomodar os novos dados. E o fato de existirem dados dos usuários que simplesmente não podem ser jogados fora e que precisam se acomodar ao novo modelo é uma imensa dor de cabeça.

Nesse caso o banco de dados relacional acaba até emperrando a melhoria do modelo de domínio.

Minha abordagem em algumas situações foi criar um utilitário que transforma o banco antigo para o novo: implementamos classes de mapeamento que tomam um objeto do modelo antigo e devolvem um do modelo novo. A partir daí fazemos um utilitário que percorre o banco de dados de produção converte os objetos e persiste em um novo banco.

Essa abordagem, entretanto, não parece a mais eficiente.

Por isso pergunto: como lidar com essa situação? Como conseguir trabalhar com o modelo de domínio livremente e ao mesmo tempo sincronizar com os dados no banco de produção?

Comment: Não tem mágica: um projeto iterativo, que abraça a mudança e incentiva o refactoring (Agile/DDD), exige que o banco possa ser mudado com relativa simplicidade também. Mudar um banco relacional nunca vai ser tão fácil quanto mudar o código, mas é preciso perseguir essa facilidade. Não é nada trivial, mas é bastante viável. Eu descreveria um ou dois métodos que você poderia usar, mas acho que daria uma resposta longa demais e estes métodos ainda dependem das tecnologias que você usa ou ferramentas que você esteja disposto a usar.

Comment: Eu cheguei até a pensar em alguns casos em usar NoSQL mas até hoje não consegui estudar muito a fundo os diferentes tipos de bancos de dados NoSQL e as situações em que vale a pena usar. Você poderia me indicar onde posso ver alguns métodos que podem ser usados para resolver esse problema?

Comment: O modelo relacional é excelente pela sua exatidão na representação do domínio, dado que você tenha conhecimento deste durante a construção, contudo ele "puro" é realmente resistente a mudanças. Já que você está considerando NoSQL saiba antes que este é um termo abrangente que se refere a qualquer tipo de banco de dados que "não é sql" então existe uma infinidade de modelos: dbs de grafos, document oriented dbs, object oriented dbs, etc. Muitas vezes uma dada representação é superior/mais flexível em um certo caso, por exemplo redes sociais são grafos naturais, mas depende do caso.

Comment: Comecei a escrever uma resposta mas o tempo acabou e, já enorme embora muito resumida, ainda não está nem em 30%! Se eu conseguir terminar outro dia eu posto aqui. Veja estes artigos: http://martinfowler.com/books/refactoringDatabases.html e http://martinfowler.com/articles/evodb.html. Veja também este meu comentário no blog de um colega: http://www.rafaelleonhardt.com.br/2012/01/12/data-tier-applications-x-code-first-migrations/. Não se assuste: é viável usar abordagem iterativa também na base de dados relacional! Eu já fiz bastante disso, com sucesso. Exige muita automação mas vale a pena.

Answer (score 1):

Sua preocupação em **não deixar que haja um grande distanciamento entre o modelo de dados relacional e o modelo de domínio é realmente importante**, porém temos que Modelo de domínio:

- Contém o conhecimento sobre um problema/conhecimento, fruto
  da colaboração entre especialistas de negócio e equipe de
  desenvolvimento;
- Possibilita ao desenvolvedor comunica-se com especialistas de negócio em uma linguagem natural;
- Tem ligação com a implementação do seu código e não com o seu banco de dados.

Citação: Encontrei no livro o seguinte trecho...

> Tecnicamente, o design de tabelas relacionais não tem que refletir o
>   modelo de domínio. As ferramentas de mapeamento são sofisticadas o suficiente para lidar com direrenças significativas.

**Ou seja, o DDD não diz para manter o seu modelo de domínio ou seu objeto de negócio sincronizado com o banco de dados**, seria ótimo se seu objeto de negócio estivesse sincronizado com seu BD, mas, nem sempre isso é possível, nem sempre você está desenvolvendo o banco a medida que você desenvolve seu código. Pelo contrário, tem casos que essa sincronização realmente não é possível, como um BD que foi criado para outro sistema por exemplo.

Então, pensando em um caso onde você tem um campo no BD relacional e você por algum motivo precisa mantê-lo, mas esse campo não existe mais no seu objeto devido a uma nova alteração solicitada, uma alternativa interessante é deixar de mapear o campo, assim, ao consultar o registro no BD que corresponda ao objeto, o campo não seria mais recuperado, seria como se o campo sequer existisse no BD.

Comment: Na mesma página do livro onde você encontra esta citação, você encontra também o Eric Evans ponderando que se a base é desenhada para um determinado model, é importante sim mantê-los próximos mesmo que às custas de algum sacrifício no model ou algum sacrifício na normalização. Apesar das capacidades do ORM, manter o mapeamento simples e legível também é muito importante. O livro seria ruim se ele dissesse "preocupe-se apenas com o domínio e pouco com a base de dados" pois esta não é a nossa realidade no desenvolvimento de software, certo?

Comment: *"Quando a base é vista como um repositório de objetos, não deixe o modelo da base e o modelo de objetos divergir muito, apesar dos poderes dos ORMs. Sacrifique alguma riqueza dos relacionamentos de objetos para mantê-los próximos do modelo relacional. Comprometa alguns padrões formais de bases relacionais, tal qual a normalização, se isso ajuda a simplificar o mapeamento dos objetos."* - Eric Evans em seu livro DDD.

Comment: E onde eu falei que isso não é importante @Caffé ???? Leia a primeira frase da resposta aí cara! "Sua preocupação em **não deixar que haja um grande distanciamento entre o modelo de dados relacional e o modelo de domínio é realmente importante**" vou até colocar em negrito rs. Favor voltar com meus pontinhos porque se você não leu isso ou entendeu diferente do que está escrito foi interpretação errada sua.

Comment: Bem, o voto é justamente de acordo com a interpretação de quem vota, não? Não se preocupe, haverá mais votos positivos na sua resposta. Na minha humilde opinião, ela não responde a pergunta. Ela se limita a se conformar com as dificuldades de manter a base atualizada conforme se atualiza o modelo.

Comment: @Caffé acho sua atitude bem estranha, está bem claro na resposta e em negrito que é importante sim manter modelo de domínio e relacional próximos, mas isso nem sempre é possível e uma alternativa foi sugerida. Acho uma resposta útil sim, com base no livro e acho sua atitude bem estranha, o intuito aqui é ajudar. **Se ela responde totalmente a pergunta ou não isso é definido por quem está perguntando**, que é quem deve marcar a resposta final que atende ao que ele estava precisando. **Sua interpretação foi equivocada, quem ler vai ver.**